# Mapping moving application from asp.net to wpf

Tags: wpf, mapquest

The company I work for has decided to create a wpf application with similar functionality to that of our website. One of the major components of the website is the use of the MapQuest javascript api.  I have been tasked with working on an alternative that would work for the wpf application.

I have done plenty of research and I have mocked up a WebBrowser control that holds an html page where the map can be built.  Unfortunately we use much more than just a map though, there are polygon geofences, points, directions, etc…  This requires (in the asp.net side) a lot of client side script to handle all of this. From what I have seen with wpf and a WebBrowser control – another layer of complexity is added to manage all of that client scripting.

My question is –

Do I continue down this path of creating a WebBrowser control? 
   Or..
Should I look at third party libraries such as GMap.NET?

**One side note. MapQuest is the only option that I have, as we pay licensing to use it.

Comment: Puttin a `WebBrowser` in a `WPF` application is NOT migrating a web application to a WPF application. Basically you're just keeping the web application and showing it via the `WebBrowser` control instead of a regular browser (Google Chrome, IE, FireFox, etc). What do you need? do you need a client/server application? otherwise just keep the web application. WPF is not a web technology. It is an AWESOME Windows desktop application technology, but it makes no sense if you need the portability of web.
I don't understand that.

Comment: The map is the only portion of the application that would require this. I'm not looking to just wrap our entire existing web application inside of WebBrowser. I'm in the research phase and we haven't pulled the trigger on using wpf - I am just looking into the possibility of using it. Unfortunately we have to use MapQuest, I know that bingmaps provides an api for wpf.

Comment: there's also a free and open source [google maps WPF API](http://wpfgooglemap.codeplex.com/). WPF is an awesome technology for all kinds of applications, it allows a clean separation between UI and logic/data and it's truly customizable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution... well, not really a solution to the problem but... Company decided to go the route of the bing map api for wpf. Going the other route with the MapQuest javascript api inside of a WebBrowser would have been a total nightmare to maintain.